# Question about batch save objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, save

I haven't seen any thing on this topic in Django's online documents.

I am trying to save a list of objects to database, but what I can do is loop through the list and call save() on every object.

So does Django hit database several times? Or Django will do one batch save instead?

Comment: Perhaps worth changing the accepted answer now that bulk_create() is available in django 1.4 and up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, batch inserts are something that Django 1.3 and prior do not directly support.  If you want to use the ORM, then you do have to call save() on each individual object.  If it's a large list and performance is an issue, you can use django.db.cursor to INSERT the items manually inside a transaction to dramatically speed the process up.  If you have a huge dataset, you need to start looking at Database engine specific methods, like COPY FROM in Postgres.

Comment: is this still true with django 1.5 ?

Comment: No - see the answer below. As of 1.4, `bulk_create()` will handle efficient bulk data inserts. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: Copy From is still far better then bulk_create?

Answer (score 38):

As of Django 1.4, there exists a `bulk_create()` method on the QuerySet object, which allows for inserting a list of objects in a single query.  For more info, see:

- [Django documentation for `bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)
- [Django 1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#model-objects-bulk-create-in-the-orm)
- [The ticket that implemented this feature](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7596)

Comment: Very nice! I should upgrade to 1.4 then.

Comment: bulk_create is awesome but, sadly it does not support inherited models. any idea to handle that?

Comment: Note in particular that "[if the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does, unless the database backend supports it (currently PostgreSQL)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)".

Answer (score 5):

From Django 1.4 exists `bulk_create()`, but, always but.

You need to be careful, using `bulk_create()` it wont call instance `save()` method internally.

As django docs says

> The model’s save() method will not be called

So, if you are overriding save method, (as my case was) you can't use bulk_create.

Answer (score 2):

This question is also addressed in [How do I perform a batch insert in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655670/how-do-i-perform-a-batch-insert-in-django/3459915), which provides some ways to make Django do this.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1913/) might be a good starting point, but as the author of the code snippet says, it might not be production ready.